# How to install new tesseract ocr language for apache/tika:2.9.1.0-full?

Tags: docker, apache-tika, tika-server

I have tried with following command, but it shows I don't have the permission

```
apt-get update
apt-get install tesseract-ocr-chi-sim
```

I can run the same command in apache/tika:1.24-full, but in the newer version it doesn't work

Maybe I need to login as root user, but I can't find a documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works

```
docker exec --user root -it container-name  /bin/bash
```

You will have root privilege by using `--user root` option